# kolmogorov backward equation intuition

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

The [kolmogorov backward equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_backward_equations_(diffusion))  equation states that the probability density of a random variable $x$ which follows $dx= \mu dt + \sigma dw$

is given by

$-p_t = \mu p_x + 0.5\sigma^2 p_{xx} $

This can be derived by applying Ito's lemma to $p(x,t)$ and setting the $dt$ term =0.

However, it is not clear to me why you can just set the coefficient of $dt =0 $

Comment: You don’t derive the backwards equation by « setting the dt term to 0 ». Also the density is found by solving the forward equation, not the backwards equation so it is unclear what you are asking actually

Comment: I think dayum is referring to Wikipedia on Itô's lemma ("Informal Derivation"), where the equation is found if u set the coefficient of $dt$ to zero

Comment: Thanks @ZRH. At some other places also, it is derived informally in a discrete case using transition equation $P(x,t) = p * P(x-dx, t-dt) + q * P(x+dx, t-dt)$ where $p$ and $q$ are the probabilities of an up and down move of size $dx$ in next interval $dt$.  However I am unclear how this translates to a continuous case.

Comment: I have seen a derivation where a trinomial transition equation is written down (up,sideways,down), and the continuous case is derived as limiting case where $dx \rightarrow 0$ and $dt \rightarrow 0$

Comment: $p(x,t)$ should be a martingale, hence its drift term should be zero and therefore you can set all terms that are multiplied by $dt$ to equal zero.

Comment: I guess by setting $dt$ to zero , they mean to differentiate the equation with respect to the expiry T and "remove" the integral over time [t, T].